# RelativeLayout for ListView item

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-relativelayout

First of all, if this question is a copy, I am sorry!!!

I have this layout for a ListView item and it doesn't work ok.
I want a center line separator, On the left of the line one number and another one on the right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/separador"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text=" - " />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/local_ptos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/separador"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="188"/>

      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/visitante_ptos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/separador"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="200"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I change this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/separador"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text=" - " />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/local_ptos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/separador"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="188"/>

      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/visitante_ptos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="200"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have this result:

[image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1899886/device-2014-05-15-122702.png)

Why??

Thanks!!!

I really want this: [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1899886/device-2014-05-15-133250.png)

I get this with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/local_ptos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="100"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/visitante_ptos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="200"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/separador"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/local_ptos"
        android:text=" - " />


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/local_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/local_ptos"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/visitante_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/visitante_ptos"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

But I don't like this code and I want the separator line vertical centered with numbers.
Sorry my English

Comment: What is your ListView parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Hope i have understood your question here is your xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/separador"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text=" - " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/local_ptos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/separador"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="188" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/visitante_ptos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/separador"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="200" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/visitante_ptos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="JPS" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/visitante_ptos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="CABA" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is that the code isn't the full code. I have 2 TextView more with the teams names. One parent right aligned and one parent left aligned. I get this with ugly code:[image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1899886/device-2014-05-15-133250.png). I want numbers near the separator line. Sorry my English

Comment: can you please paint it , how would your app look like and upload it here and maybe i can help you ?

Comment: This is my problem, layout_toRightOf and layout_toLeftOf don't work, what I want don't matter, but why doesn't work that???

Answer (score 0):

You needed following attributes: `android:layout_toLeftOf` and `android:layout_toRightOf`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/separador"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text=" - " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/local_ptos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/separador"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="188" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/visitante_ptos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/separador"
        android:text="200" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Of course, but it doesn't work. I don't know why!!! This is the result: [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1899886/device-2014-05-15-122127.png)